# Archive-Custom-Post-Type order by Event Date, ASC, and hide events that have completed

Tags: custom-post-type-archives

I am building a site for a personal project and I have a series of Events created via a Custom Post Type.

I then need these events to be displayed by a custom meta value (Event Start Date) and in ASC order. I have managed to figure that out and the code I used is below:

```
/*CUSTOM ARCHIVE FOR EVENTS*/
    function events_pagesize( $query ) {
    // exit out if it's the admin or it isn't the main query
    if ( is_admin() || ! $query->is_main_query() )
    return;
    // so its not admin, and its the main query, is it the tr-events post archive?
    if ( is_post_type_archive( 'tr-events' ) ) {
    // it is!! Set the posts_per_page to 6
    $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 4 );
    $query->set( 'order' , 'asc' );
    $query->set( 'meta_key', 'wpcf-tr-order-date');
    $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value');
    return;
    }
    }
    add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'events_pagesize', 1 );
```

My question is how to hide posts past a specific date AND how would I also create an Archive view to display Events that have completed? I've seen tons of posts about this and most options break pagination. This option as a function in the functions.php gets me 70% there.

Answer (score 1):

I quess that it would be easiest for you to store date as unix timestamp in post meta - than you can easily filter posts by post meta less than current [timestamp](http://www.php.net/strtotime) (or any other date timestamp).

See this example (not exactly for your code, but you'll catch the punch line:

```
$args = array(
   'post_type' => 'tr-events',
   'meta_key' => 'wpcf-tr-order-date',
   'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
   'order' => 'ASC', //DESC, its up to you
   'meta_query' => array(
       array(
           'key' => 'wpcf-tr-order-date',
           'value' => strtotime('now'),
           'compare' => '<',
       )
   )
 );
 $query = new WP_Query($args);
```

As I mentioned, you'll have to rewrite this piece of code to `$query->set();` format